# Split string at word boundaries without losing whitespaces or newlines

Tags: python, regex, string, text, split

Suppose I have a string like this which contains (multiple) whitespaces and newlines:

```
"\n\n\nmy  string \n"
```

I want this to be split into:

```
['\n', '\n', '\n', 'my', ' ', ' ', 'string', ' ', '\n']
```

How could I get this? I suppose I need a regular expression?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eQ3yC3/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex [`\w+|\W`](https://regex101.com/r/eQ3yC3/1) and find matches

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('\w+|\W')
>>> p.findall('\n\n\nmy  string \n')

['\n', '\n', '\n', 'my', ' ', ' ', 'string', ' ', '\n']
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/eQ3yC3/1)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @user2177047 : glad to help you :)